# How to set "User Interaction Enabled" on UITextViews in code

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I have the following problem: I got a view with two text fields and a UITextView (non editable, but scrolling) to show some infos. When the keyboard is shown I slide the whole view up so both text fields and the keyboard are shown. When the user clicks outside of the text fields I hide the keyboard and move the view back down.

This works only if the user does not click on the UITextView to hide the keyboard. If I turn of "User Interaction Enabled" in IB it works but UITextView won't be scrollable.

How do I set the "User Interaction Enabled" in code so whenever the keyboard is shown I would disable it? Or is there a better way to solve this?

tia
Stefan

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the `userInteractionEnabled` property:

```
//UITextView *textView;
textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```